# Compare multiple values of dictionary and aggregate result

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda, python-itertools

I have this use case where I need to ignore `sku`, `targetFlag` and `qualifierFlag` while comparing the values and if any dictionary of the list has the same values other than these three and it should be aggregated in one dictionary along with all these three key and values.

Can somebody tell me what modification I need to do or any other better solution to get the proper result.

The solution I tried till now can take only one value while comparing from the above options:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd

d = OrderedDict()

d = (pd.DataFrame(lst)
            .groupby(['endDate','storeCode', 'startDate', 'promoName','targetFlag', 'qualifierFlag'])
            .sku
            .agg(set)
            .reset_index()
            .to_dict('r'))
```

```
lt = [{
   "sku":"40428200",
   "storeCode":"316",
   "endDate":"05445100",
   "promoName":"2201:316 SUPER 37100548200",
   "startDate":"40505000",
   "targetFlag":"0",
   "qualifierFlag":"0",
},
{
   "sku":"4567",
   "storeCode":"316",
   "endDate":"05445100",
   "promoName":"2201:316 SUPER 37100548200",
   "startDate":"40505000",
   "targetFlag":"1",
   "qualifierFlag":"1",
},
{
   "sku":"12345",
   "storeCode":"123",
   "endDate":"05445100",
   "promoName":"2201:316 GRAND 0548200",
   "startDate":"40505000",
   "targetFlag":"1",
   "qualifierFlag":"0",
},
{
   "sku":"40428200",
   "storeCode":"316",
   "endDate":"18840100",
   "promoName":"2201:316 AVI 37125790200",
   "startDate":"40505000",
   "targetFlag":"1",
   "qualifierFlag":"0",
}
]
```

The expected result will be something like this

```
[
 {'endDate': '05445100',
  'promoName': '2201:316 GRAND 37100548200',
  'startDate': '40505000',
  'storeCode': '123',
  'res': [
      {
        'qualifierFlag': '0',
        'sku': '12345',
        'targetFlag': '1'
      }
  ]
  },
 {'endDate': '05445100',
  'promoName': '2201:316 SUPER 37100548200',
  'startDate': '40505000',
  'storeCode': '316',
  'res': [
      {
        'qualifierFlag': '0',
        'sku': '40428200',
        'targetFlag': '0'
      },
      {
        'qualifierFlag': '1',
        'sku': '4567',
        'targetFlag': '1'
      },
  ]
  },
 {'endDate': '18840100',
  'promoName': '2201:316 AVI 37125790200',
  'startDate': '40505000',
  'storeCode': '316',
  'res': [
      {
        'qualifierFlag': '0',
        'sku': '40428200',
        'targetFlag': '1'
      }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

def key_func(x):
    return (x["storeCode"], x["promoName"], x["startDate"], x["endDate"])

lst = sorted(lst, key=key_func)

result = [
    {
        "storeCode": k[0],
        "promoName": k[1],
        "startDate": k[2],
        "endDate": k[3],
        "res": [
            {
                "sku": x["sku"],
                "qualifierFlag": x["qualifierFlag"],
                "targetFlag": x["targetFlag"],
            }
            for x in list(v)
        ],
    }
    for k, v in groupby(lst, key=key_func)
]
```

result:

```py
[
    {
        "storeCode": "123",
        "promoName": "2201:316 GRAND 0548200",
        "startDate": "40505000",
        "endDate": "05445100",
        "res": [{"sku": "12345", "qualifierFlag": "0", "targetFlag": "1"}],
    },
    {
        "storeCode": "316",
        "promoName": "2201:316 AVI 37125790200",
        "startDate": "40505000",
        "endDate": "18840100",
        "res": [{"sku": "40428200", "qualifierFlag": "0", "targetFlag": "1"}],
    },
    {
        "storeCode": "316",
        "promoName": "2201:316 SUPER 37100548200",
        "startDate": "40505000",
        "endDate": "05445100",
        "res": [
            {"sku": "40428200", "qualifierFlag": "0", "targetFlag": "0"},
            {"sku": "4567", "qualifierFlag": "1", "targetFlag": "1"},
        ],
    },
]
```

Jean-Marc Billod's method uses `set` as the aggregation function so only unique values are returned.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Does the following code do the trick?

```
d = (pd.DataFrame(lst)
       .groupby(['endDate','storeCode', 'startDate', 'promoName'])['sku', 'targetFlag', 'qualifierFlag']
       .agg(set)
       .reset_index()
       .to_dict('r'))
```

Comment: but it is creating one value instead of two for `targetFlag` and `qualifierFlag` if the values are the same in two dictionaries. Any idea to avoid that?